# v-select update var without v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Because I'm using v-select in a loop and I need to mark each of the loop iteration. I want to be able to add the selected value to an array, to check if the value exists and then add it or change it, something like this:

```
             <v-card-text>
                <ul>
                  <li v-for="ap in ['1','2','3']" :key="app">
                    <v-select
                      :items="findelem(appi)"
                      item-text="number"
                      item-value="number"
                     @input="check_update_array(_mark_ , _VALUE_)"
                    ></v-select>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
```

and have check_update_array(*mark* , *VALUE*) as a method that checks and updates the array

is this possible ?

Edit:

I'll try to be more explicit, I want to do a v-for and to iterate over an array
for each selection I want to send to a function the position (value in iteration) and the selected value:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="ap in ARRAY">
    <v-select
...
    @input="check_update_array(ap, SELECTED_VALUE)"
></v-select>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

if I do @input="check_update_array" the SELECTED_VALUE is passed as param to the function and if I do @input="check_update_array(ap)" the position in iteration is passed.

Comment: Could we also see `check_update_array`? Would help clarify for me what you would like to do. (I am confused on which array you would like to update)

Comment: check_update_array(mark,value) is a function that adds to an array or updates that array if the elemement is already added. The array will start empty and at the end ( after selecting will look like this [{'mark':'mark1', 'value':'selected_value_1'}, [{'mark':'mark2', 'value':'selected_value_2'} .... ]. Wanted beheviour: if I put @input="check_update_array(_mark_ , _VALUE_)" then the array will be check if any element has it's 'mark' === '_mark_'  if it does it will update if not will add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the following code.
I took your code as a basis.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
  <v-app>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-text>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(ap, index) in ['1','2','3']" :key="index">        
             <v-select
                    :items="findelem()"
                    item-text="number"
                    item-value="number"
                    label="My Select"
                    @input="check_update_array"
             ></v-select>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p>
      {{ elements }}
      </p>
    </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
    </v-app>v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: function() {
        return {
            elements: []
        }
      },
      methods: {
        check_update_array(value) {
            this.elements.push(value);
        },
        findelem(appi) {
            return [{'number':'some element'},{'number':'another element'},{'number':'third element'}]
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ewatch/gn3eyxp2/

However some context was missing for me from your code regarding the "appi" parameter for the findelem function and the parameters "*mark*" and "*VALUE*" for the check_update_array function.

The function that is bind to the @input event receives the selected value as parameter already (see documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event).

I hope it helps.
Please let me know if you have any questions.

Best regards,
ewatch

Comment: To clarify a little: with  ':items="findelem()"' I'm just finding a specific object in another array, so this can be ignored or treat it exactly like you wrote it. Your code works fine and pushes the selected value in the selector to the elements array; but I also need to pass to the "check_update_array" function a marker to be checked if the pushed value already exists in the elements array. So: if ia put @input="check_update_array" I will run the function: check_update_array(value_from_selected) and I need it to be run like: check_update_array(value_from_selected, indentifier)

Comment: Hi Arkon-v,
I checked a little bit the implementation of the v-select component. Although the element works like a <select> element of HTML it only use a single input field to save the current value. That means it won't have an index for it's values to identify which position is selected.
My opinion is that as you are filling the v-select with data you need yourself identify the position by comparing the selected value with the values you put in to be rendered. Does that make sense and would it be possible for you case ?

Comment: Hi, thanks @ewatch, to have both the position (in iteration) and the selected value bound together I've ended up creating an array and have each v-select in the v-for with a v-model:  v-model="an_array[position]" im my case:  v-model="selected[ap]"

Comment: Great :-)! Nice that this exchange helped you. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a data named 'selected_array'

```
data() {
    return {
      selected_array:[]
    }
}
```

Now in your component, it should be look like this.

```
<v-card>
   <v-card-text>
      <ul>
          <li v-for="ap in ['1','2','3']" :key="app">
                    <v-select
                      :items="findelem(appi)"
                      item-text="number"
                      item-value="number"
                     @chanage="check_update_array"
                     return-object
                    ></v-select>
                  </li>
        </ul>
    </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

Then in your check_update_array function, you code should look like this.

```
check_update_array(data){
   let item_exist = false

   this.selected_array.forEach(item => { // check if value exists.
       if (item.value == data.value) {
          item.mark = data.mark
          item_exist = true
          return
       }
   })

  if (!item_exist) {              // if not existing then append
     this.selected_array.push(
         {mark:value, value:value}
     )
  }

 item_exist = false // reset value
}
```

Just make sure that your `findelem(appi) is an array of objects containing mark and value elements`

Comment: thank you for answering and for your time, but how do I pass the selected item value to the function; how can  _VALUE_ be that value

Comment: I updated my answer, you have to return object for you access the current object selected

Comment: you have to return object fin order in order for you to access the current object selected and compare it if it was already existed

Comment: added an edit I hope is more clear now, I want to pass to the function in @input the value of the selected item and the position, the position is a string